# How to make my own Dynamic DNS Server?

Tags: ubuntu, dns, webserver, dynamic-dns, ddns

So, here is the thing.
I have a server with static IP and a domain (example.com), and I have some other servers with changing locations and dynamic IPs and no domains. I wanna give them my subdomain (like 1.example.com); and when my costumers wanna go to 1.example.com, I want my main server forward them to the other server.
So I need to run a program on my other servers that listen to their IPs and send them to main server, after that I need a program that run on my main server that listen to other servers for their IPs and update the bind subdomain records.
I look the entire the Internet and I didn't find anything suitable for my situation.

PS: I got a situation that my network is limited and I can not use "no-ip" or "duckdns" or similar.
I have apache2 on all the servers and they are all using "Ubuntu server".

What is the solution and what should I DO???!

Comment: A Google search for "dynamic dns server software" throws up a number of options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after so many tries and research I decided to write my own python program for Dynamic DNS Server.
So for the first part I will post here the example of python codes that I used, consider that the code is not complete and I will post edit this post later.

**ServerSide:**

```
#----- A simple TCP based server program in Python using send()$



import socket
import logging

# Create a stream based socket(i.e, a TCP socket)

# operating on IPv4 addressing scheme

serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)



# Bind and listen

serverSocket.bind(("**Localhost**",**port**))

serverSocket.listen(5)

print ('Hello client!')

# Accept connections

while(True):

    (clientConnected, clientAddress) = serverSocket.accept()

    print("Accepted a connection request from %s:%s"%(clientAddress[0], clientAddress[1]))



    dataFromClient = clientConnected.recv(1024)
    print(dataFromClient.decode())



    # Send some data back to the client

    clientConnected.send("Hello User".encode())
    user = dataFromClient
    cip = clientAddress
    LOG_FILENAME = '/log.txt'
    logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.DEB$
    file = open("log.txt","r+")
    file.truncate(0)
    file.close()
    logging.debug(cip)
    logging.debug(user)
    logging.debug("--------------------------------------------$
```

**ClientSide:**

```
import socket



# Create a client socket

clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)



# Connect to the server

clientSocket.connect(("**Server's public**",**port**))



# Send data to server

data = 'Hello server'

clientSocket.send(data.encode())



# Receive data from server

dataFromServer = clientSocket.recv(1024)



# Print to the console

print(dataFromServer.decode())
```